Hibernate Envers: custom RevisionEntity for specific database/schema only (multi database setup, multi datasource setup)
Goal:
I want to delete an entry in the database, but protocol it in the (existing) history.
Row from main table gets deleted, but in the _audit table the history is readable. In addition I want to protocol the user and timestamp of the deletion in the revinfo table. So I use the Hibernate Envers way of doing it instead writing my own logic (e.g. soft delete).
Problem:
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
Setup:
The project has two datasources, but each with different purposes. In addition, the "problematic" datasource has multiple schemas.
application.properties
datasource2.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4:3306?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
# ...
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=mydatabase
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.envers.default_schema=mydatabase
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=mydatabase
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true
hibernate.integration.envers.revision_listener=com.project.data_access.entities.UserRevisionListener

CustomRevisionEntity:
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(UserRevisionListener.class)
@Table(name = "revinfo", schema = "mydatabase")
public class CustomRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456789L;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}

UserRevisionListener:
public class UserRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {
    @Override public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        CustomRevisionEntity revision = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            revision.setUsername(authentication.getName());
        } else {
            revision.setUsername("anonymous");
        }
    }

Deletion method from service:
@Transactional(transactionManager = "customTransactionManager", rollbackForClassName = "java.lang.Exception")
public Boolean deleteSomeObject(Long id, String access_token, Authentication auth) {
   // some checks
   if (objectExists) 
   {
        customRepo.deleteById(id);
        return true;
   }
    
    return false;
}

MyDatasourceConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "customEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager", 
    basePackages = {"com.project.repo"},
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class myDBConfig {

    // ...

@Bean(name = "customEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.project.data_access.entities")
                .persistenceUnit("datasource2").properties(getHibernateProperties())
                .build();
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getHibernateProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("hibernate.default_schema", "mydatabase");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        return props;
    }
}

revinfo table:
CREATE TABLE `revinfo` (
  `REV` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `REVTSTMP` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REV`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=637 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci

So I tried to set the schema as much as possible, but after a deletion get always the same error. I don't want to set the default schema in the connection string, because multiple schemas are used (but even that I tried without success).
What configuration am I missing? Should I use a custom audit strategy instead?
